# Getting current item in ViewPager when adding dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `Fragment` that contains `TextView`s and one *custom timer* `View`. There is an interface with a callback method for `Fragment` to implement interface's method to listen *custom timer* `View` changes and then to update `TextView`s.

[image]

Attaching listener interface to *custom timer* `View`:

```
@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow()
{
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    mTimerViewPager =
            (TimerViewPager) ((Activity) getContext()).findViewById(R.id.view_page_timer);
    TimerPagerAdapter timerPagerAdapter = mTimerViewPager.getAdapter();
    mListener = (TimerListener) timerPagerAdapter.getFragment(mTimerViewPager.getCurrentItem());
}
```

At the beginning, ViewPager contains one `Fragment` and callbacks update `TextView`s properly. But when I add one more `Fragment` and come back to the first one, callbacks update `TextView`s in the second one. After adding third one, second one does **not** update third one...So it's not like I'm missing "-1" operation.

Function for adding new Fragment in `TimerPagerAdapter` (extension of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`):

```
public int addPage(Fragment fragment)
{
    int position = mCount;
    mCount++;
    fragments.put(position, fragment);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    return position;
}
```

- `mCount` is number of pages.
- `fragments` is `SparseArray<Fragment>`

I have no other idea how to get proper current item. I am also not sure whether the `ViewPager` is a good idea for dynamic adding/removing (but I haven't found any other alternative. Tabs probably?)

I have provided code that I think is necessary. If you need more, just let me know in comments.

Comment: why don't you just update the textview from inside the fragment that contain it? where do you use you custom timer view

Comment: @NguyễnHoàiNam, I'm not sure what you mean. I'm trying to update `TextView`s from inside the fragment, custom timer view is inside as well. But custom timer view only overrides `onTouchEvent` method and fragment needs to listen to the change - so the fragment needs to be a listener.

Comment: Since you use your view inside the fragment where it is attached to, please try to setup the listener dynamically. I don't see setup listener in onAttachToWindow is a good practice. Furthermore, try to implement your custom view's state saving to store your value. Fragment will call its view to restore their state.

Comment: @NguyễnHoàiNam, thank you. I tried to move setting the listener to the function in fragment, instead of attaching it in the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @NguyễnHoàiNam comment I was able to achieve proper cooperation between fragment and custom timer view. Instead of `onAttachedToWindow` I use dynamic setting of the listener:

```
public void setTimerListener(TimerListener timerListener)
{
    mListener = timerListener;
}
```

Comment: Does this help you to update correct value from your timer View? I think you still need to implement your View's state saving, so when your fragment return to live again, and if it is available to restore its previous state, your View state (latest timer value) will be restored too.

Comment: @NguyễnHoàiNam Yes, it does. I implemented saving state using before, using `BaseSavedState`

Answer (score 0):

ViewPager should be fine in this situation. There's a method on ViewPager for getting the current item.

```
int viewPager.getCurrentItem()
```

[Docs here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#getCurrentItem()) That should work.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, I'm using that (look at the last line in the first code block above `mTimerViewPager.getCurrentItem()`). Works great until I dynamically add new fragment.

Comment: How are you updating the fragment?

Comment: using an interface with callback method `public class TimerFragment extends Fragment implements TimerListener`. Method uses only one parameter that stands for custom view `public void onTimerChange(Timer timer)`. So I get values from custom timer view and update TextView inside the fragment